# How to perform a search operation test in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

I am trying to conduct a stress testing and I need to test the search operation of the web application. So I recorded the search operation using Blazemeter. [image]. In the image I have three sampler recorded. So there are two get and one post request. But I am not sure should I keep them all for testing or only the sampler query request? Also is this the right way to do it because I will be doing stress testing on the website? Please give me your advise. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter test must represent real life user activity as close as possible.

Before searching you need to open the search page, don't you? So I would expect at least one GET request prior to the POST request which performs the search. We don't know the specifics of your application and your screenshot doesn't tell the full story, moreover it's resolution is super low so I can only recommend cross-checking the requests which JMeter does with the requests which are captured by the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and send the same amount of requests keeping the same network pattern as the real browser do.

Also real users don't hammer the application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations or to type a search query so it worth considering adding a suitable [timer(s)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers/) to simulate these [think-times](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time)

And finally if you record only one hard-coded query and will run it with multiple threads/iterations you might get false-positive results because it can be cached on multiple levels (load balancer, in-memory cache, database cache, etc.) so it worth coming up with a list of potential search criteria, put them into a CSV file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each user would "search" for something different on each iteration but at the same time the test would be repeatable.

Comment: Hi Dmitri Thanks for your answer. But I have this three smapler below:                           https://-----l/api/search/products/autosuggest?q=wine, https://----/zoek?query=wine and https://----/api/search/products/query.  Should I keep this api calls sampler also?